# Google Visualization API giving error 'google undefined' when deployed on server but works well on local machine

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I am using Google Visualization API to generate organization chart. When I try to run the code on local machine with either IE 8.0 or IE 9.0, it works well, but when I deploy the same on my remote server, the chart is not visible on IE 8.0. It works on IE 9.0.

On IE 8.0, I get error: 'google' undefined. When using IE debugger, error is shown on this line:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
```

Entire script is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });

    function drawChart() {
        var hdValue = document.getElementById("<%=hdData.ClientID%>").value;
        var response = $.parseJSON(hdValue);
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Employee');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var row = new Array();
            row[0] = response[i].Employee;
            row[1] = response[i].Manager;
            data.addRow(row);
        }
        var options = {
            title: 'My Office Hierarchy'
        };
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(drawChart);

</script>
```

Comment: Have you verified that all of the JavaScripts are downloading successfully? In particular, if this page is on a HTTPS URL, the insecure http://ajax.googleapis.com/ download is probably blocked by default.

Comment: This might not be the cause of your problem, but you shouldn't be calling your drawChart function from a document ready event, as there is no guarantee that the API has loaded by that point; use `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` instead.  If the error is really being fired from `google.load()`, then this isn't the cause of your immediate problem, but I recommend making the switch anyway.